# How can I merge/migrate TFS source code into existing Visual Studio Team System project preserving work items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a situation where at a point in our project's life, we needed to split off work item tracking and source control into 2 separate TFS projects, with the work items being in a VS Team Services project, and the source on-prem in TFS 2013.

The reason at the time being, we needed to grant access for our stakeholders to the product backlog, without them being on the corporate network where TFS is hosted.  At the time there was concerns about security of the source code, hence the whole project was not lifted and shifted, just the backlog.

Now we're realizing some of the security concerns were not warranted, and we are missing out on the integration of ALM provided by a single project having both responsibilities, and would like to merge our source control out into the cloud-based VSTS project.

The problem is, the migration tools are overwriting the Work Items in VSTS.  Is there some way we could merge, preserving that data, or any alternative to merge these two things together somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at the [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) here if you want to migrate source code history.  Bear in mind that it's not going to be perfect (data time stamps will not be the same etc.).

If you can get away with it then just stick the latest code in VSTS and consider the on-prem server your archive should you need to go back.  That doesn't tend to be too popular so you'll be wrestling with the integration tools.  It's not the most friendly thing to use but mostly it will get the job done.

When you configure your session, you will want to choose Team Foundation Server\VersionControl.xml for your configuration.  Then select a One-way-migration between your on-prem and VSTS.

You'll need to install VS 2012 or at least the Team Explorer.

**Edit** Coincidentally I had to do this myself so I blogged about the process [here](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/richarderwin/2016/01/27/InstallingTheTFSIntegrationToolsToMigratesyncBetweenTFS2015AndVSTS.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but we're trying to do something more along these lines:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs

This will migrate all the source code, and history to VSTS, but it won't merge the code into an existing project, where our backlog of work items are currently

If we could import our work items into the migrated project with source, we'd be golden, but I guess this feature isn't available yet... see this:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2264946-import-export-data-from-visual-studio-online

Comment: Hi Matt, the TFS integration tools will do what you want, they're just a little temperamental.  An alternative is to use the OpsHub tool and then migrate your backlog from your existing VSTS project to the new migrated backlog.